# Project (with Guice, Gson and Mockito) + Java module system possible without using "open" extensively?

Tags: java, module, mockito, gson, guice

I am trying to add `module-info.java` to my project to make it conform with Java module system. However, I am struggling with a lot of issues as I am using libraries which are doing some injections like:

- Mockito / Mockito-Inline -> *when using spy(..) only, no problem with mock(..) so far*
- Guice
- Gson

To make my code work again I must either open my module using `open module <name> { .. }` or extensive use of `open <my-package> to <other-module>`.

With Mockito I even am enforced to open my packages to `ALL-UNNAMED` module. When not opening my packages to the world then I am facing issues like:

- `InaccessibleObjectException` --> resolution: open package to specific module(s)
- `NullPointerException` when using `Mockito.spy(..)` --> resolution: open package to `ALL-UNNAMED` module

Here is my concern:
With so many `opens` rules I am almost giving up the strong encapsulation that was introduced with Java module system. Either I am on the wrong path or is this really the correct way we have to deal now when we want to use the Java module system?

Clarification is appreciated **if the actual workaround `open module .. { .. }` is the *best way*** when working with dependencies like guice, gson, ... . Is there a reference project somewhere that demonstrates how to keep the strong encapsulation and using guice, gson, etc.?

KR, Christoph